# Extract HTML comments using C++ std::sregex_token_iterator

Tags: html, c++, regex, token

I'm trying to extract the comments section from HTML source. It is sort of working but not quite.

```
<html><body>Login Successful!</body><!-- EXTRACT-THIS --></html>
```

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = 
    "<html><body>Login Successful!</body><!-- EXTRACT-THIS --></html>";

    // Regular expression to extract from HTML comment 
    // <!-- comment -->
    regex  r("[<!--\r\n\t][\r\n\t-->]");

    for (sregex_token_iterator it = sregex_token_iterator(
                                        s.begin(), 
                                        s.end(), 
                                        r, 
                                        -1); 
         it != sregex_token_iterator(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "TOKEN: " << (string) *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I guess my main question is that is there a way to improve my regex expression?

Comment: if ECMAScript supported atomic groups, you could find `"(?>(<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\\s+(?>\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\\s*>)[\\S\\s]*?</\\2\\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\\w:]+\\s*/?)|(?:[\\w:]+\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\\s*/?)|\\?[\\S\\s]*?\\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:\\[CDATA\\[[\\S\\s]*?\\]\\])|(?:ATTLIST[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\\S\\s]*?))))>))*?(<!--[\\S\\s]*?-->)"` replace with `$1` where the comment is in _group 3_.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: Will do...however stil a few minor issues I need to iron out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a `std::string` that contains more than one comment section:

```
string s = "<html><body>Login Successful!</body><!-- EXTRACT-THIS --><p>Test</p><!-- XXX --></html>";
```

### Removing the Comments and Printing the HTML tags

If you want to remove the HTML comments from this string, you can do it like this:

```
regex r("(<\\!--[^>]*-->)");

// split the string using the regular expression
sregex_token_iterator iterator = sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r, -1);
sregex_token_iterator end;
for (; iterator != end; ++iterator)
{
    cout << "TOKEN: " << (string) *iterator << endl;
}
```

This code prints:

```
TOKEN: <html><body>Login Successful!</body>
TOKEN: <p>Test</p>
TOKEN: </html>
```

### Removing the HTML Tags and Printing the Comments

If you want to extract the comments from the string, you can use the `std::sregex_iterator` like this:

```
regex r("(<\\!--[^>]*-->)");

std::sregex_iterator next(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
std::sregex_iterator end;
while (next != end) {
    std::smatch match = *next;
    std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
    next++;
}
```

This code prints:

```
<!-- EXTRACT-THIS -->
<!-- XXX -->
```

### Parsing Comment Tags Manually

Another option is to find and iterate through the opening and closing tags manually. We can use the `std::string::find()` and `std::string::substr()` methods:

```
const std::string OPEN_TAG = "<!--";
const std::string CLOSE_TAG = "-->";

auto posOpen = s.find(OPEN_TAG, 0);
while (posOpen != std::string::npos) {
    auto posClose = s.find(CLOSE_TAG, posOpen);
    std::cout << s.substr(posOpen, posClose - posOpen + CLOSE_TAG.length()) << '\n';
    posOpen = s.find(OPEN_TAG, posClose + CLOSE_TAG.length());
}
```

Comment: I actually want to extract the comment body EXTRACT_THIS as part of one of the tokens.

Comment: So you want all token (including the comments) or just the comments (skip the other HTML tags)?

Comment: I just want to extract the comments...is there a more efficient way than tokenizing?

Comment: Thanks for all the help Hugo. So your solution is working for the simple case that I gave at the time. I wanted to simplify it so I guess that's kind of my fault. This works if I have a simple word within the comments like: EXTRACT_THIS. If I have XML tags it doesn't give any output.
Is it possible you can provide an updated regex expression to extract the XML within the comments:
string s = "<html><body>Login Successful!</body><!-- <tag-one>tag-one</tag-one><tag-two>tag-two</tag-two> --></html>";

Comment: @AnkurShah I've added a new section that explains how to do this without regular expressions. That third solution should solve your problem.

Comment: Works great! You have been extremely helpful much appreciated!